# Custom Cells are created, but not displayed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I've used [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@musawiralisha/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722) to populate a UITableView with custom cells that represent balances. When stepping through the code, I witness the correct amount of cells get created (only 4 with the current test data) and their labels' text set correspondingly.

My problem is when the table is displayed on the screen, only the first row/cell is displayed.

Any insight as to why this could be occurring would be greatly appreciated!

**Removed old code.**

BalanceCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BalanceCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *amountLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *modifiedLabel;

@end
```

**EDIT:**
My TableView delegate methods are now as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_balances count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    BalanceCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BalanceCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.backgroundColor = [_hex colorWithHexString:_themeColourString];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(BalanceCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Balance *item = [_balances objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.nameLabel.textColor = _themeColour;
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name;

    cell.amountLabel.textColor = _themeColour;
    cell.amountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", item.symbol, item.value];

    cell.modifiedLabel.textColor = _themeColour;
    cell.modifiedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.modified];

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
    return 94;
}
```

As @Sebyddd suggested, I now register the NIB in the viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BalanceCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

These changes may make my code more correct but [still only the first cell is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsOhI.jpg).

Comment: Have you set the cell identifier to "Cell" for your custom cell?

Comment: Yeah, I do that in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

If cells are getting created and returned properly I guess height is not being set propery. By default I beleive all cells have a height of `44`. If your cell exceeds this height it might not get displayed.

You can tell the tableview to adjust height for every cell using `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate

In that delegate just return your cells height.

EDIT:

You are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` which will return *A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.*

Instead use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` which will return *A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This method always returns a valid cell.*
You need to register the nib/class for that custom cell in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The cell's height in the Interface Builder is 90, so I have been returning 94 from that delegate for the duration.

Comment: I have edited my question with my new code listings and a screenshot. It's still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"BalanceCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell = [[BalanceCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! It's very strange, trying this caused the second row to be displayed and no others. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/crhfJzR)

Comment: Try to register the custom cell in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Still just the first cell.

Answer (score -1):

Use this tuto : http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/ , your tuto is a bit outdated, and hard to follow !

Comment: I don't think that helps his problem.

Comment: That tutorial does not use custom cells. I have tried allocating and initialising an instance of BalanceCell when the cell is nil too, but this caused the the UILabels to be nil and unsettable.